# Registration button on my eventbooking form hangs .. jquery/ajax issue?

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla

I use MijoEvents as eventbooking component in Joomla. After upgrade the registration form is not working. Support was not helpful and I try to debug on my own. My Javascript/Jquery/AJAX skills are not good enough to find out what's happening. After clicking on the confirm-registration button the wheel-icon turns and then nothing happens. It should open the accordions below for Billing Details etc but it doesn't.
View at site : https://dorotheahealing.com/classes/the-technology-scanning-learning-to-feel-energies/registration/individual?event_id=60
I think something with the Jquery / AJAX processing goes wrong
Thankful for every hint ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Change every `live()` function to `on()`, live is depreciated for jquery 1.11